# Append two textfield values and displays in third textfield

Tags: java

I have 3 `TextField`s: `enumber`, `qt`, `quotnum`. Here `enumber` has an event handler which fetches a value from a database and displays is the `TextField` `qt`. When I put `1` in `enumber` I get the max value according to the database displayed in `qt`. Now I want to append these 2 values and displays in `quotnum`, but I can not achieve it:

```
enumber.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) 
    {
        try
        {
            String query="Select max(`quotationNumber`)+1 as max from quotation ";
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                String a= enumber.getText();
                int num = rs.getInt("max");
                int inc=num+1;
                qt.setText(""+inc);
                quotnum.setText(a+"__"+ qt.setText(""+inc)); //here got error qt.setText(""+inc) cant append
            }

            // demo.setText(i);
            rs.close();
            pst.close(); 

        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling the setter method instead of getter. Setters are void they don't return anything. you're trying to concat with setter method hoping it will return some value. 
You may try something like `qt.getText()` or simply do the `quotnum.setText(a+"__"+inc))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qt.setText(""+inc);
quotnum.setText(a+"__"+ qt.setText(""+inc));
```

Did you read the API for the `setText(...)` method? That method returns "void" so you can't use it as a parameter for another method.

You have already set the text of the "qt" text field, so know you need to "get" the text of the "qt" text field:

```
qt.setText(""+inc);
quotnum.setText(a + "__" + qt.getText());
```